# Getting input of one or more rows ending with char sequence not only seperated by space or new line - java

Tags: java, string

I need to read a user input that begins with "begin", "BEGIN" or "Begin" and the input can be one or more rows until user writes "end", "END" or "End". End is separated from previous String(s) with non-letter character (new line, space or "}" and so on).

I have tried something like this, but I know that's wrong.

```
String everything = sc.next();
while (true) {
    String part = sc.next();
    part.toUpperCase();
    if (part.equals("END")) {
        everything = everything.concat(part);
        break;
    } else {
        everything = everything.concat(part);
    }
}
```

Comment: `part = part.toUpperCase();`  Strings are immutable.

Comment: Or just use `equalsIgnoreCase` in place of `equals`.

Comment: Thanks didn't notice this, but that's not the main problem.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what your problem is.  Do you need to set the separator of your `Scanner` to something other than just space?

Comment: I need to end user input with "end" and the seperator before that word can be anything except letter.

Comment: Just getting user inputs to the point when there is sequence "end". It's little hard for me to explain, I am new to coding and English isn't my native language...

Answer (score 0):

I think your trying to do too many things at once.  Your approach could work, but it's making things more complicated.  First, get the user input and store it in a list.  Once he presses END, then write some code that concatenates it, or whatever you want to do with it.

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> all=new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        String part = sc.next();
        if (part.toUpperCase().equals("END")) {
            break;
        }
        all.add(part);
    }
//then do whatever you want with that list.
```

Comment: But there is the problem, when user inputs for example ")end" the program should end getting inputs.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Then change :   .equals("END")
to .contains("END")